# Subset list based on TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r

Say I have a list

```
> foo

[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] TRUE
```

How do I find which values return TRUE, so that I get a list like

```
[1] 1 2 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `which(foo == TRUE)`

Comment: `which(foo==TRUE)`. Some might say `which(unlist(foo))` but consider `which(unlist(c(foo,"hah!")))`

Comment: @A.Webb `which(list(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 3.3) == TRUE)` is not correct either

Comment: `which(sapply(list(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 3.3, 'hi'), isTRUE))`

Comment: @rawr Post as an answer, this one is obviously a bit more tricky than we first suspected.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is unlist it and ask which ones are TRUE via which.

```
which(unlist(foo))

> foo <- list(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
> which(unlist(foo))
[1] 1 2 4
```

@Per the comment:

In case you're not sure all your elements are of the same type, you can also do:
which(foo == TRUE)

Personally, I'd rather it throw an error as implicitly, in my mind, if I do a query over all the elements, I assume each one is comparable. However, the concern is valid.

Comment: Great, this is what I went with.

Comment: See my comment under the question. You probably shouldn't assume your list is all the same type, since it is a list after all.

Comment: @rdevn00b: Great if you like the answer, be sure to click the check mark to mark it as "correct". This way people will know and it gives positive points to the response.

Comment: @A.Webb: That's not quite what the question is asking but I'll add it to my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

As my previous comment, here is a (more robust) solution:

```
which(foo == TRUE)
[1] 1 2 4
```